# How to access a remote database using CURL and PHP?

Tags: php, sql, database, curl

I have this homework problem:

```
Use CURL to implement the following:

For each company web site, create a php web app/link that shows a list of users from your own company.
Assume we have a group of 3 (Company A, Company B and Company C). Thus, we have
list_of_users_A that is stored in a database A in Company A host system
list_of_users_B that is stored in a database B in Company B host system
list_of_users_C that is stored in a database C in Company C host system
Each company web site needs to create a web link that shows list_of_users from all companies. You can access your local list_of_user via normal php database call, but you need to access remote company's database via CURL calls.
```

I understand how to access a webpage and get the information using CURL, but I've been googling and don't understand how to access a remote database using CURL.

I can access a remote database using mysqli_connect, but that's not using CURL is it?

Thanks!

Comment: you dont need to access the db with curl, you have to return a list (json probably) of all users in the db through the website

Comment: Each of the company web sites would need to provide a simple web service that would return the list of users from their local database.

Comment: @ Don't Panic This part confused me "you need to access remote company's database via CURL calls." Is what we're simply supposed to do is make a webpage with a list of our own company's user's list, and then CURL to get information from other company's webpage that contains that information?

Comment: Is it basically. Companies A, B, and C create a webpage using PHP to get and display on that webpage their own company's users list, and then ie: Company A uses CURL to get users list from webpage of Company's B & C?

Comment: Yes, that's what it sounds like to me. Each company would need to respond to two requests. 1) their local user list from the database, 2) their local user list merged with the lists requested from the other companies via curl.